# Authorization issue with python request

Tags: python, sonos

I am trying to authenticate users and I am getting invalid
{'error': 'invalid_request'}

bellow is my code

I am following the guide on https://developer.sonos.com/build/direct-control/authorize/

```
import base64
import requests
```

```
        client_secret = "*******************************"
        client_id = "*******************************"

        combine_id = f'{client_id}:{client_secret}'

        base64_id = base64.b64encode(combine_id.encode("ascii"))
        base64_id = base64_id.decode("UTF-8")

        code = request.data["code"]
        state = request.data["state"]


        headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8',
            'Authorization': f'Basic {base64_id}',
        }

        data = {
            'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
            'code': code,
            'redirect_uri': 'http://localhost:8000/sonos'
        }

        response = requests.post(
            'https://api.sonos.com/login/v3/oauth/access', headers=headers, data=data)

        print("response : ", response.json())
```

Comment: I am getting this same error {'error': 'invalid_request'} and if I change the payload from 

          ```payload = {'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
            'code': code,
            'redirect_uri': 'http://localhost:8000/sonos',
        }```

to 

```payload_ = f"grant_type=authorization_code&code={code}&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fsonos"

```

the error changes to {'error': 'unsupported_grant_type'}

Comment: Another thing I noticed is that the code I am receiving after signing in with Sonos is shorter than the one in the documentation example it is about 8 character long

Comment: @msanford the second comment might not explain much to you I thought you are associated with sonos.

Comment: According to https://developer.sonos.com/reference/authorization-api/create-token/ "invalid_request" means "Client does not have permission to use this API." Please revisit the guide you linked. Note that it says "The redirect URL must meet the following requirements: 
It must be publicly routable. 
It must be HTTPS." I don't know why you're getting "unsupported_grant_type" when you change things. Perhaps you can update your question with some pseudo code request & response values.

Comment: @yrg Thanks a lot my redirect url didn't match